# Symfony2 custom provider challenge with HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, oauth, facebook-oauth

The goal: make auth system with OAuth providers (e.g. facebook)

The Solution: I installed and set up the HWIOAuthBundle, made custom user class, everything works and authenticated. So, after callback from oauth provider security layer asking provider for loadUserByOAuthUserResponse method that loads user from database...

The problem: ... But when symfony tries to authenticate user it actually calling provider for loadUserByUsername method, and passing there only string with username. But facebook oath not returning username provider, it's actually returning resource username that is looks like 10152039919326906, and passing NULL to username. And when security layer asking for loadUserByUsername it's calling it with NULL parameter.

Here is some of parts code from dev:

```
class OAuthUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface, OAuthAwareUserProviderInterface 
{

  protected $em;
  protected $className;
  protected $repository;

  function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry, $className) {
    $this->em = $registry->getManager();
    $this->repository = $this->em->getRepository($className);
    $this->className = $className;
  }

  public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
  {
    $username = $response->getUsername();
    $nickname = $response->getNickname();
    $realname = $response->getRealName();
    $email    = $response->getEmail();

    $resourceOwnerName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();

    $user = $this->repository->findOneBy(
      array('resource' => $resourceOwnerName, 'resourceUsername' => $username)
    );

    if (null === $user) {
      $user = new $this->className;
      $user->setUsername($nickname);
      $user->setResourceUsername($username);
      $user->setResource($resourceOwnerName);
      $user->setRealname($realname);
      $user->setEmail($email);
      $user->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());

      // facebook crutch
      if (null == $user->getUsername()) {
        $user->setUsername($username);
      }

      $this->em->persist($user);
      $id = $this->em->flush();
    }

    if ($user) {
      return $user;
    }
  }

  public function loadUserByUsername($username) {

    $user = $this->repository->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));
    if (!$user) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf("User '%s' not found.", $username));
    }

    return $user;
  }
```

So, i think, i need come crutch, that will pass to loadUserByUsername email or other field if username is NULL, and to rewrite it a bit for search DB not only in username field.

There lot of situation similar like this that can freak out because of loadUserByUsername. E.g. twitter oath doesn't returning email, but returning username. Is there some way to rewrite interface where loadByUsername calling?